# Zephyr For Jira Test Management Plugin of Jenkins hangs while sending test report to Jira

Tags: jenkins, jira, jira-zephyr

I am trying to use Zephyr For Jira Test Management Plugin in Jenkins to create test cases automaticly and update their status. What works is that Jenkins creates test case and it is fine, but issue is that it hangs and not updates Jira's issue (pass/fail). Does anyone know is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Connection is working and validated: 
[Connection image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzS2O.jpg)

Plugin gets information at post build actions: [Post build config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSwiE.jpg)

Jenkins console output says that build is successful, and then hangs: [Success message and hanging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAkO2.jpg)

Error message from cmd that I don't understand: [Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Xtwp.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. At the post build actions (second picture), publish test results to Zephyr for Jira - changed from cycle *Ad hoc*, to *New Cycle*. And it worked!

Comment: Have you tested your case with the new Plugin Zephyr Scale?